# Does ServiceStack Integration With IdentityServer Require A Web Api Project?

Tags: servicestack

I'm testing out ServiceStack to see how much faster the development is with this product rather than with Asp.Net Core's Web API or similar products.

I have successfully set up Service Stack with my own configuration of IdentityServer4 and everything runs fine.

My confusion is whether working with IdentityServer4 means I am required to now maintain a Web Api project along with ServiceStack? What's the reason the API is there?

I can see that I can make direct calls to the endpoints (requiring Authentication, roles, etc.) and that works in conjunction with IdentityServer4.

Would love some insight on why the Web Api project is needed and whether I can just completely get rid of it, as I was under the impression ServiceStack was a replacement for WCF/Web Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack's [mvcidentityserver](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentityserver) project template that's used in the documentation of [ServiceStack's integration with IdentityServer4](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-identityserver) was an enhanced version of Identity Server's **"OpenID Connect Hybrid Flow Authentication and API Access Tokens"** example project that used to be maintained at https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/

The project template contains Auth integration examples with ServiceStack, MVC & Web API. The Web API examples were inherited from the existing IdentityServer's example project, which is optional and can be completely removed.

Comment: Thank you! Great job on the framework. As soon as I’m done testing it, if it works for the project I’m considering it for, I’ll purchase it.